# Entering `y` automatically when encountering many Unix prompts

Tags: perl, unix, glusterfs

I have to automate some prompt-interactions with GlusterFS using Perl. I made a module `delete()` that automatically deletes gluster volume; however, it asks `(y/n)` for each volume. How can I provide this answer in advance? My script below also seems to hang during execution.

```
`my $vol_name = params->{vol_name};    
gluster volume stop $vol_name ;    
my $string = gluster volume delete $vol_name;    
print "$string\n\n\n";`
```

Comment: [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) is a general solution to interact in your Perl script with other interactive programs.

Comment: You appear to be missing some quotes. That's not valid Perl code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the Expect.pm module?

- https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Expect/Expect.pod

It basically is a copy of the Tcl based expect command:

- http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

It is designed explicitly for interacting with programs.

Answer (score 2):

Try piping yes into the command

```
my $string = yes | gluster volume delete $vol_name;
```

A working example from my code!

```
yes | rm *.txt
```

Comment: `rm` has the `-f` option, you know.

Comment: ...or you know, not specifying `-i`.